# why my python code skipping the first line and making changes starts from second line

Tags: python, string

I have python code as below, I'm removing spaces(after ": " & ", ") with below code, but it is making changes only to the second line successfully, and skipping the first line, not sure what I'm missing here

```
import os
import requests
import json
import sys
import re
import fileinput
filepath=os.path.expanduser('~')
cleanedLine = ''

path = sys.argv[1]
# Opening JSON file
f = open(path,'r')
# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data=json.load(f)

for i in data:
    if 'channels' in i:
        temp = i['channels'][0]
        if 'alertid' in temp:
            temp.pop('alertid')
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
p=open("test_alerts.txt","w")
sys.stdout=p
for i in data:
    if "channels" in i.keys():
        print('|'.join([json.dumps(i['name']),
              json.dumps(i['apps']),
              json.dumps(i['channels']),
              json.dumps(i['viewid'])])
             )
#        sys.stdout=orig_stdout
#        p.close()
    with open('test_alerts.txt', "r") as f:
       for line in f.readlines():
          pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
          str = re.sub(pattern, '', line)
          print(str)
```

Original file:

```
"test-everything"|["messages,kubelet.service"]|[{"triggerinterval": 
"12h", "triggerlimit": 1, "integration": "email", "immediate": false, 
"terminal": true, "operator": "presence", "emails": 
["yugendhar.reddy@fun.com"]}]|"3fddf26cb4"
"test-logs"| 
["kubelet.service,kernel,messages,audit.log,auditd,crio,g::d62e01bbb6"]| 
[{"triggerinterval": "24h", "triggerlimit": 1, "integration": "email", 
"immediate": false, "terminal": true, "operator": "presence", "emails": 
["yugendhar.reddy@fun.com"]}]|"0df42550ee"
```

Expected output:

```
"test-everything"|["messages,kubelet.service"]|[{"triggerinterval":  
"12h","triggerlimit":1,"integration":"email","immediate":false,
"terminal":true,"operator":"presence","emails":
["yugendhar.reddy@fun.com"]}]|"3fddf26cb4"
"test-logs"| 
["kubelet.service,kernel,messages,audit.log,auditd,crio,g::d62e01bbb6"]| 
[{"triggerinterval":"24h","triggerlimit":1,"integration":"email",
"immediate":false,"terminal":true,"operator":"presence","emails": 
["yugendhar.reddy@fun.com"]}]|"0df42550ee"
```

Comment: use `str1` instead of `str` as it is inbuilt dtype

Comment: Did you strip ```\n```? ```line.strip("\n")```

Comment: @Sujay, where exactly should I add this

Comment: ```str1 = re.sub(pattern, '', line.strip("\n"))```

Comment: its not working either

Comment: @MikeM, its giving the same result, skipping first line....
with open('test_alerts.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
        str1 = re.sub(pattern, '', line)
        print(str1)

Comment: Try without re regex, by using python regex instead....... Otherwise, upload your original fine and expected result and I can help with the code.

Comment: @Joshua, I have edited the question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Check your `re` statement because not using it e.g.:

```
>>> with open('lines.txt', "r") as f:
...  for line in f.readlines():
...   x = line.strip().replace(": ", ":")
...   x = x.replace(", ", ",")
...   print(x)
... 
"test-everything"|["messages,kubelet.service"]|[{"triggerinterval":
"12h","triggerlimit":1,"integration":"email","immediate":false,
"terminal":true,"operator":"presence","emails":
["yugendhar.reddy@fun.com"]}]|"3fddf26cb4"
"test-logs"|
["kubelet.service,kernel,messages,audit.log,auditd,crio,g::d62e01bbb6"]|
[{"triggerinterval":"24h","triggerlimit":1,"integration":"email",
"immediate":false,"terminal":true,"operator":"presence","emails":
["yugendhar.reddy@fun.com"]}]|"0df42550ee"
```

Seems fine.

As a side note: do you really need to compile `pattern` for each pass through the loop?